# typescript: concatination order in generated file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a ts (angularjs) project and uses a reference file to specify the order of dependencies. But, it is not ordering correctly. In the generated `js` file, controller file is last, where it should be before module. Hence, it gives error at runtime as `TestCtrl` referenced in the module

```
test.am.controller(mod.test.TestCtrl.ID, [mod.test.TestService.ID, function (srv) {
                return new mod.test.TestCtrl(srv);
            }]);
```

so, why the ordering in `references` file is not followed? Any why in the generated file `controller` file is not included before `module`, though it is referenced in the `module.ts` file.

I use grunt-ts for compiling the files, and the command is

```
Running "ts:dev" (ts) task
Verifying property ts.dev exists in config...OK
Files: src/controller.ts, src/module.ts, src/names.ts, src/reference.ts, src/service.ts
Options: allowBool=false, allowImportModule=false, compile, declaration=false, mapRoot="", module="amd", noImplicitAny=false, noResolve=false, comments, removeComments=null, sourceMap, sourceRoot="", target="es3", verbose=false, fast="watch"
Compiling...
Cleared fast compile cache for target: dev
Fast compile will not work when --out is specified. Ignoring fast compilation
Using tsc v0.9.5
"/Users/test/order2/src/controller.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/module.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/names.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/reference.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/service.ts" --sourcemap --target ES3 --module amd --out out.js
```

ps: grunt-ts supports `reference-file-generation`, but I do not want to use it at the moment.

reference.ts

```
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="names.ts" />
/// <reference path="service.ts" />
/// <reference path="controller.ts" />
/// <reference path="module.ts" />
```

names.ts

```
//names section

/// <reference path="reference.ts" />

module mod{
    export module test{
        export var ID = "test"
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
//service section

/// <reference path="reference.ts" />

module mod{
    export module test{

        export interface ITestService {
        }
        export class TestService implements ITestService {
                        static ID = ""           
        }
    }
}
```

controller.ts

```
//controller section

/// <reference path="reference.ts" />

module mod{
    export module test{

        export interface ITestCtrl {
        }

        export class TestCtrl implements ITestCtrl {
            static ID = ""
            constructor(private rec:ITestService) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

module.ts

```
//modules section

/// <reference path="reference.ts" />

module mod{
    export module test{
        export var am:ng.IModule = angular.module(test.ID, ['ngRoute']);
        am.controller(TestCtrl.ID, [TestService.ID, (srv:ITestService) => new TestCtrl(srv)]);
    }
}
```

generated file (js)

```
//names section
/// <reference path="reference.ts" />
var mod;
(function (mod) {
    (function (test) {
        test.ID = "test";
    })(mod.test || (mod.test = {}));
    var test = mod.test;
})(mod || (mod = {}));
//service section
/// <reference path="reference.ts" />
var mod;
(function (mod) {
    (function (test) {
        var TestService = (function () {
            function TestService() {
            }
            TestService.ID = "";
            return TestService;
        })();
        test.TestService = TestService;
    })(mod.test || (mod.test = {}));
    var test = mod.test;
})(mod || (mod = {}));
//modules section
/// <reference path="reference.ts" />
var mod;
(function (mod) {
    (function (test) {
        test.am = angular.module(mod.test.ID, ['ngRoute']);
        test.am.controller(mod.test.TestCtrl.ID, [mod.test.TestService.ID, function (srv) {
                return new mod.test.TestCtrl(srv);
            }]);
    })(mod.test || (mod.test = {}));
    var test = mod.test;
})(mod || (mod = {}));
//controller section
/// <reference path="reference.ts" />
var mod;
(function (mod) {
    (function (test) {
        var TestCtrl = (function () {
            function TestCtrl(rec) {
                this.rec = rec;
            }
            TestCtrl.ID = "";
            return TestCtrl;
        })();
        test.TestCtrl = TestCtrl;
    })(mod.test || (mod.test = {}));
    var test = mod.test;
})(mod || (mod = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=out.js.map
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the command passed into the compiler :

```
"/Users/test/order2/src/controller.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/module.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/names.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/reference.ts" "/Users/test/order2/src/service.ts" --sourcemap --target ES3 --module amd --out out.js
```

The order will be determined by the file order passed in the command *because* you all files reference `reference.ts` *unless* all you pass to the compiler is *reference.ts*.

**So solution:** either use reference file generation by grunt-ts, so grunt-ts will only ask the compiler to compile `reference.ts`

OR

Have explicit `<reference` tags pointing to the files you *need* to be included *before* the current file.

BTW grunt-ts the latest version can generate these reference tags for you e.g. `///ts:ref=controller` will generate a reference tag to `controller.ts`. I need to document these transform but am busy with projects.

Comment: thanks basarat. I am pretty sure I tested the alphabetical ordering by naming the files a.ts, b.ts,.. and found tsc is arranging them in the order they refer (even though the files are passed in the alphabetical / reverse order). Anyway, the feature to generate the ref tag as in the second option sounds great. will try it out. thanks.

Comment: for what it's worth I had similar issues, but ability to order my js files when compiled into a single one solved my problem : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#javascript-generation

Answer (score 2):

Typescript's documentation was useful to me on solving this once I figured out that the generation order was the problem. [Typescript vs. Javascript Generation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#javascript-generation)

> When a output file is specified via out in combination with a reference file via reference then grunt-ts uses the generated reference file to order the code in the generated JavaScript.
>
> Use reference.ts to specify the order for the few files the build
> really cares about and leave the rest to be maintained by grunt-ts.
>
> E.g. in the following case the generated JavaScript for
> someBaseClass.ts is guaranteed to be at the top, and the generated
> JavaScript for main.ts is guaranteed to be at the bottom of the single
> merged js file.

```
/// <reference path="someBaseClass.ts" />

// Put comments here and they are preserved

//grunt-start
/// <reference path="autoreference.ts" />
/// <reference path="someOtherFile.ts" />
//grunt-end

/// <reference path="main.ts" />
```

Everything between grunt-start and grunt-end is generated and maintained by grunt-ts. If there is no grunt-start section found, it is created. If reference.ts does not exist originally, it is also created.

Although sometimes all this feels like trying to follow the rules to [Fizbin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v77SF4TFUoM) that Captain Kirk makes up on the fly.